# $dy/dx=e^{-x^2} , y(2)=6$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

hey so I'm trying to solve this equation using separable method ( an example from my book). It says it isn't an elementary function ( I don't really understand that, but a function that can't be created using basic algorithm ( ?)).

Anyway, the book uses t as a "dummy variable" and they integrate both side of the equation using my Initial Value, any one could explain to me why? I can't seem to understand how that method would make sense, or be mathematically right.

Edit**: The second paragraph refers to what the author did. he considered using $t$ as a dummy variable of integration therefore giving:

$$\int_{2}^{x} \frac{dy}{dt}dt = \int_{2}^{x} e^{-t^{-2}} dt$$

Comment: Separating variables and integrating we get $y = \int e^{-x^{2}} dx \ (*)$ but notice that there is no way to give a solution to $(*)$ using arithmetic operations and in terms of trig functions, exponentials, polynomials etc, the "elementary functions" (see wikipedia, I'm sure it has something on it). Also, could you give more information on what you asked in the second paragraph, I'm a bit confused on what you mean.

Comment: There is a 99.999% chance you have either copied down the problem incorrectly or the book has a typo, or the author is a sadist. Are you sure it's $e^{-x^2}$ and not say, $(e^{-x})^2$?

Comment: @AlexR. He did say there is no solution in terms of elementary functions, so it probably is $e^{-x^{2}}$.. I laughed at the sadist part though.

Comment: Hum @AlexR. I am 100% sure. I am using  Advanced Engineering Mathematics 5th edition. As I said, the author used a dummy variable t and ended up with int(dy/dx)dt from x --> 2 = int ( e^-t^2) dt from 2--> x

Comment: @Mattos I just explained ( sorry didn't tag) what the author did by using "dummy variable t".

Comment: @Marc-AndreLeclair Make an edit to your original post to include the new information so others can see what you have done. Also, typeset it in latex so we can read it properly please (just put the mathematics in a pair of $ signs).

Comment: For an initial condition $y(x_0)=y_0$, you can write the solution as $$y(x)=y_0+\int_{x_0}^xe^{-x^2}\,dx$$

Comment: @Mattos Tried, couldn't get the integral and limits to show.

Comment: @user170231 is there a reason behind that, for why it works if you use the initial condition compared to a integral with no limits?

Comment: @Marc-AndreLeclair Fixed your post, tell me if it is what you wanted. Also, user170231 has used the fundamental theorem of calculus to provide the "solution", it is equivalent to what you have in your book.

Comment: @Mattos yes thank you ! and the fundamental theorem of calculus is very far in my memory ( 3 years). BUT, isn't it proving the "link" between derivatives and integration? I thought that was done over a close interval and not over an open one.